# Date math not giving expected result

Tags: macos, date

I've seen several examples (including this [post](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/doing-date-math-command-line-part-i)) and it seems simple enough but I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong (I know that post is for linux but I tried w/ the `date` command on a linux machine and go the same result there)

An example command and ouput

```
me@mymachine~$ gdate -d '2019-10-19 01:37:02 +7 days' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-19 14:37:02
```

I would expected the result to start with `2019-10-26`.  So it seems that it's not parsing my input right?

What's even weirder (to me anyway), is if I take off the time part of the input it works as expected

```
me@mymachine~$ gdate -d '2019-10-19 +7 days' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-26 00:00:00
```

Comment: `gdate -d '2019-10-19 +7 days  01:37:02' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`?

Comment: You're my hero, if you write up that answer I'll give the check

Answer (score 0):

#### Analysis

I made some tests in Debian 9, studied `man 1 date` and `info date`. The latter contains more information about how strings like `2019-10-19 01:37:02 +7 days` are interpreted.

Preliminary notes:

- My answer uses `date` because this is the tool in Debian. (Use `alias date=gdate` to test my commands with `gdate` without editing them each time).
- It seems your timezone is roughly equivalent to `TZ=UTC+4`.

I tried to replicate your result:

```
$ date -d '2019-10-19 01:37:02 +7 days' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-19 20:37:02
```

My result is different, this indicates timezones matter. To really replicate your result:

```
$ TZ=UTC+4 date -d '2019-10-19 01:37:02 +7 days' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-19 14:37:02
```

---

#### Explanation

It turns out `+7` in your "misbehaving" command is interpreted as `UTC+7` and `days` is interpreted as `+1 days`. Compare:

```
$ TZ=UTC+4 date -d '2019-10-19 01:37:02 UTC+7 +1 days' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-19 14:37:02
```

(Note `TZ=UTC+4` means [UTC-04:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9204:00) while `UTC+7` in the string means [UTC+07:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B07:00). The inconsistency with signs is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104088/108618).)

The mysterious result is not so mysterious now.

---

#### Quirk

What is really weird is this:

```
$ TZ=UTC+4 date -d '2019-10-19 01:37:02 UTC+7 days' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-25 21:37:02
```

Apparently it's not `UTC+7` and `days` (meaning `+1 days` as above) but rather `UTC` (meaning `UTC+0`) and `+7 days`:

```
$ TZ=UTC+4 date -d '2019-10-19 01:37:02 UTC+0 +7 days' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-25 21:37:02
```

---

#### Solution

Move the `+7 days` substring towards the beginning, so it appears before `01:37:02`. This way `+7` wont be interpreted as `UTC+7`:

```
$ date -d '2019-10-19 +7 days 01:37:02' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-10-26 01:37:02
```

Now `01:37:02` in the input string is interpreted according to whatever timezone `date` considers right. The result* should be the same for me in Europe, fellow users in America, Australia, anywhere. This is why I dropped `TZ=UTC+4`, it doesn't matter anymore.

<sup>*I mean the *string of characters* printed by `date` should be the same. Different users will interpret the same string in different timezones and they will get different moments in reality. In this sense their results are different. In the same sense their inputs are different.</sup>